# Ошибка: "Cannot modify header information"

Tags: php, cookie

Что значит ошибка:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\localhost\www\index.php:13) in Z:\home\localhost\www\inc\mod\reg\2.php on line 8

Строка на которую указывает ошибка:

```
setcookie('id', $id);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтоб долго не расписывать, [просмотрите короткую статью](http://phpfaq.ru/headers) по вашей проблеме или [более полную информацию тут](http://mcgrifin.ru/2011/09/%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-warning-cannot-modify-header-information-%E2%80%93-headers-already-sent-by-output-started-at/).